# Scrapy returns wrong font

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i am using scrapy to collect some data and when i try to scrape tag element from craiglist it returns font different from other elements. How can i make font in the left column look like font in the right one?
Here is the picture and the code i am using:

```
  item["tag"] = " ".join(response.xpath("//p[@class='attrgroup']/span/b/text()").extract()[0])
```

[image: How can i make font in the left column look like font in the right one?]

Comment: Could you copy and paste the actual text in column A, rather than screenshotting?

Comment: Sure here you go: 2 0 1 3   D o d g e   o d o m e t e r :   4 7 0 0 0

Comment: You're using `" ".join`, which adds a space between all of the items in the iterable.

Comment: @TimMcNamara That was the problem! :D Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `response.xpath("string(//p[@class='attrgroup'])")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a space between each of the letters:

```
apunch@dlsyd00012:~/code/analytics/src$ echo -n '2 0 1 3 D o d g e o d o m e t e r : 4 7 0 0 0'|hexdump -C
00000000  32 20 30 20 31 20 33 20  44 20 6f 20 64 20 67 20  |2 0 1 3 D o d g |
00000010  65 20 6f 20 64 20 6f 20  6d 20 65 20 74 20 65 20  |e o d o m e t e |
00000020  72 20 3a 20 34 20 37 20  30 20 30 20 30           |r : 4 7 0 0 0|
```

You can use the following to extract every second character but there seems to be a deeper problem:

```
response[0::2]
```

Could you post the URL of the exact page you are using?